# I am trying to apply a yaml file into my cluster but getting error "ensure CRDs are installed first"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

resource mapping not found for name: “istio-gateway” namespace: “” from “./release/istio-manifests.yaml”: no matches for kind “Gateway” in version “gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1”
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: “frontend-route” namespace: “” from “./release/istio-manifests.yaml”: no matches for kind “HTTPRoute” in version “gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1”
ensure CRDs are installed first

Tried to use different API version in the file but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway API is outside of GKE and needs to be enabled in the cluster. Google will install the Gateway CRD into GKE. After that you can create a Gateway resource via Kubernetes. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways

If you're using Terraform to manage the cluster:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/website/docs/r/container_cluster.html.markdown#nested_gateway_api_config

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "general_cluster" {
  ...
  gateway_api_config {
    channel = "CHANNEL_STANDARD"
  }
}
```